# How to create a font file(TrueType , OpenType , etc) based on bitmaps of characters

Tags: c#

It is a homework for me to create a font file (like OpenType,which can be used in the Windows operating system).
Given some bitmaps of different Asia characters, I have already extracted their outlines which are now represented by segments and cubic Bezier curves. 
The problem is how to put the information into the font file.
I don't know whether the FreeType Project has this kind of module to layout font files.
My problem is how to create a font file quickly and easily.

Comment: TrueType is a highly non-trivial format, not well documented either.  This can't be a real homework assignment unless you are expected to create a device font.  A .fon file.  They are easy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as quick and easy for fonts. Although there are free trials for automatically converting bitmaps to fonts (actually your assignment automated). Look for [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net) for the hard way. Look for [FontLab](http://www.fontlab.com/font-converter/fonmaker) for the lazy way.

Comment: I have to write my own program,so FontLab can't help...BTW,I have never used open source project before. Could you give me some tips? Are you familiar with FontForge?

Comment: Open source is easy: get what you want and return what you can. In fact, my answer here is a contribution in itself.

Comment: FontForge is an open source font editor program. It is rather antiquated but it is said to serve many peoples' purposes. See [here](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/source-build.html) for the source.